# Request permission for android 13 (Android API level 33) using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

how do I request permissions for music and audio, notifications and photo and video for android API level 33 using Xamarin forms

Comment: Is there something wrong with the first hit on google? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android

Answer (score 2):

In xamarin form, you can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android) to achieve this.

For example,if you want to take photo and video, you need to request permission `Permissions.Camera`.

You can first check the status of `Camera` and request it with code `status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();`

Please refer to the following code:

```
    public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndRequestCameraPermission() 
    {
        var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>();

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            return status;

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        {
            // Prompt the user to turn on in settings
            // On iOS once a permission has been denied it may not be requested again from the application
            return status;
        }

        if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.Camera>())
        {
            // Prompt the user with additional information as to why the permission is needed
        }

        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();

        return status;
    }
```

**Note:**

1.I have tested above code on android emulator (android 13), and it works properly.

2.If you want to take photo and video, you can also use [Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android) directly.

And you can refer to the official sample [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/tree/main/Samples). For example, for how to take photo and video ,please check [MediaPickerPage.xaml](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Samples/Samples/View/MediaPickerPage.xaml) and [MediaPickerViewModel.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Samples/Samples/ViewModel/MediaPickerViewModel.cs).

3.for other permission, you can also refer to above code.

Comment: this only works with camera, media picker on android 13 doesn't work, works ok on android 12, seems to be with the new permission that need to be granted on new android